# Postgres - SELECT FOR UPDATE with union all

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to put row level lock on a table in one postgres function.

```
do $$ 
declare tabname text :='locktest' ;
begin
execute 'create temp table temp1 as 
    select v.* from (
        select row_number() over (partition by a.id) as row_num,a.* 
        from '||tabname||' a,locktest2 b where a.id=b.id and b.val=111
        union all 
        select row_number() over (partition by a.id) as row_num,a.* 
        from '||tabname||' a,locktest2 b where a.id=b.id and b.val=222 
    )v where v.row_num=1 for update';
   raise notice 'Completed';
end $$;
```

But while compiling it , getting below error.

```
ERROR:  FOR UPDATE is not allowed with UNION/INTERSECT/EXCEPT
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The way the statement is written, the database does not know in which table to lock the rows.

Rewrite the query along these lines:

```
SELECT ... FROM
   (SELECT ...
    FROM tab1
    WHERE ...
    FOR NO KEY UPDATE) AS t1
  UNION ALL
   (SELECT ...
    FROM tab2
    WHERE ...
    FOR NO KEY UPDATE) AS t2;
```

`FOR NO KEY UPDATE` is the correct lock if you plan to update. `FOR UPDATE` is the lock if you intend to delete.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz Albe. It worked. Through error because of windows function but i modified query a bit and it worked. I intend to do the update/delete and insert few new rows. Hope FOR UPDATE will be suitable lock.